# Call class member of another JSAPI object from root JSAPI object (created by prepscript)

Tags: javascript, plugins, callback, firebreath

Looking at [this page from firebreath.org](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Plugin+Lifecycle) I found this excerpt:

> You can return a JSAPI instance to a JavaScript caller in the form of a JSAPIPtr and use that to make calls on a different JSAPI object, e.g. plugin().method1().method2() will call method1() on the Root JSAPI object and method2() on the JSAPI object returned in the first call.

Any examples?

## My objective:

I want to call another class's (which is also implementing FB:JSAPIAuto) member (say ABCAPI:FB:JSAPIAuto ) through my root JSAPI object which is created automatically by the prepscript i.e. same as described above by creating the JSAPIPtr of the class. Am I right here?

Also, whether the JSAPI object of ABCAPI that was created by me should **also** get a plugin reference or not?

I went through [this page](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/firebreath-tips-dealing-with-jsapi-objects/) too, but am not able to follow.

Till now, I could create a method returning FB::JSAPIPtr which had the value of another Class (implementing FB::JSAPIAuto) pointer.

A little example would be a great help here!

**Another doubt:
How do you expose a simple c++ class(not extending any Firebreath class) to the Javascript so that i can access its members?**I found a v8 Javascript engine thing.Don't have any idea about this. I want my plugin to be available for all other browsers too apart from chrome.Do i need this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are a couple of things here.  First, the prep script doesn't create JSAPI objects for you -- that was fbgen.  This is an important distinction because you will run the prep script many times, but fbgen you only run once to create the project skeleton.

Next, you're making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  A JSAPI object is just a class object; if you have a reference to it in C++, you can call a member of the other class just like you would any other object.  There is nothing magical about it, except maybe when you give it to javascript, and then just that the methods you expose to javascript are the only ones you can use.

What you haven't explained is where the reference to the second JSAPI object comes from.  Are you passing it in from javascript? If so, things get more tricky, and you'll have to call it using ->Invoke like you would a method on any other javascript object passed in from the page.  Did you create it in c++? If so, then you just use it like any other object.

As to whether or not the hypothetical ABCAPI object should get a plugin reference or not, that's totally up to you.  The Root JSAPI object doesn't need one, it's just for your convenience in case you want to access the plugin.

For examples, go look at [FBTestPlugin](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/tree/master/examples/FBTestPlugin) in the firebreath code base.  It has examples of nesting JSAPI objects and such.

Comment: Want to see the debug flow of this FBTestPlugin .do u have a demo project?How to arrange these cpp files in the VS2010 solution

Comment: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Examples for more info on the examples, and if you start at http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Getting+Started you'll find instructions on how to build firebreath plugins for your platform

Comment: let me tell you what i did, I ran fbgen.py. it generated framework.ran the prepscript2010. Next bit:**copied the example .cpp and .h files in the examples folder to the plugin project generated.**I know this is not the right thing to do.So what is?Cause the fbgen had already created a project without any examples sources included under it.

Comment: thanks for making this so simple,Kudos to your Fb Team.Do check my another question!

Comment: you don't need to run fbgen to run examples.  There are instructions on the build pages for building examples! Basically you run "prep2010.cmd examples" and it'll put the build files in buildex/.  I don't mind helping, but if you would go find the answers yourself -- by reading the getting started info that answers all of this -- your progress will go a lot faster